# Kubernetes setup with different networks for intra and inter-cluster communication

Tags: kubernetes, calico, cilium

I have this use case: Setup multiple k8s clusters that can communicate with each other. I also have one network per cluster for intra-cluster communication and another network for inter-cluster communication and for external access in general. Like below:

[image]

I am currently leveraging flannel as the network plugin. My understanding is that flannel does not support this use-case (assumption).

Is this something I can achieve with a different CNI plugin? Do I need multiple CNI plugins / plugin instances / a CNI multiplexer?

In case anyone implemented something similar, feedback is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Update: Multus-cni is not an option as it does not support NodePort on secondary interfaces https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni/issues/727